# How to open new tab in browser in selenium 3.0?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have tried multiple actions but it is not working. 
It always **close the first tab** and then it open link in the same page.

```
// Driver is launched
package WebBrowserCommands;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class OpenBrowser 

{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/ss108/Desktop/Util/SELENIUM SUPPORT/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // Driver is launched

        //We have two ways
        boolean Indriectway = true;
        //Boolean to understand both method

        if(!Indriectway){
            //Using String to take value.
            String URL = "https://www.google.com";
            driver.get(URL);

            String PageSourceFirst = driver.getPageSource();
            //We have took title in PageSourceFirst
            System.out.println(PageSourceFirst);

            //Get Title Command
            String TitleFrist = driver.getTitle();
            //We have took title in TitleFirst
            System.out.println("Tile of WebSite is " + TitleFrist);

            //Get Current URL
            String CurrentURLFirst = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println("Current URL is " + CurrentURLFirst);

            Actions act=new Actions(driver);
            act.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"))).perform();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            act.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();       
            // Try to open page using right click and action arrow down **but it is not working**

            driver.close();

        }else {
            //Using directly
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
            String PageSourceSecond = driver.getPageSource();
            System.out.println(PageSourceSecond);

            //Get Title Command
            System.out.println("Tile of WebSite is " + driver.getTitle());
            //Get Current URL
            System.out.println("Current URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.quit();

        }
    }
}
```

Second method 
1- Same result getting

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/ss108/Desktop/Util/SELENIUM SUPPORT/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);  
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Third method

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

however none of them work for what I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

Each time main is run a new driver is created. The if-then-else is then used, but it is with a new driver each time.  after each use `driver.close();` closes the tab

Try creating a program structure that creates the driver once and then has methods that reuse that driver without closing it between tests.

See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/1993/8992

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a link on the current page that opens in a new window/tab. Then switch to the new window handle. Here is the C# code I use:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Injects a link on the current page and then clicks on that link (which opens a new tab).
    /// </summary>
    public static void OpenUrlInNewTab(IWebDriver driver, string url)
    {
        // Define the script
        string script = "var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='" + url + "';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);return a;";
        // Execute the JavaScript
        IWebElement element = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
        // Click the new element
        element.Click();
        // Switch to the new tab
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it using the JS `'window.open'` in my `executeScript` method in Protractor.

```
describe('Open a new window', ()=> {

  it('opening a new window', function() {      

     browser.executeScript('window.open()').then(function () {
         browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
               var secondWindow = handles[1];
               browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
               browser.switchTo().window(secondWindow).then(function () {
            // do whatever you want to do in new window
               });     
               var firstWindow = handles[0]
                browser.switchTo().window(firstWindow).then(function () {
                    console.log("Returning back");
              });
           });             
        });
     });
   });     
 });
```

You can try this using the JavaScript executor method for the corresponding language bindings. This works in Python too.